# How to display Date attribute in layered navigation?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, layered-navigation, date

I want to display Date attribute in layered navigation. Magento default  date attribute configuration doesn't allow `Show in Layered Navigation in frontend` value to be set.How can I do that?

Comment: Layered Navigation used only with catalog attribute input type Dropdown, Multiple Select and Price

Comment: Yes, but all the Products in my client's website are different types of "Reports" which has "date" as one of the attribute. My client wants to filter products(these reports) based on date in layered navigation